# nginx default redirects and custom redirects

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx, routes

OS debian 8;
im trying to write nginx config what will 
1) redirect all requests from root domain.a to domain.b
2) redirect all requests with route from domain.a/$1 to domain domain.a/api/route/$1

I was able to acomplish 2) but when i type domain.a in browser, it shows nginx default page. I expected to forward it to domain.b

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name domain.a; 

#should redirect all other requests to domain.b , but it not happens
    return 301 domain.b;

# correctly redirects from domain.a to domain.b api
    location ~/(.*)$ {
        return 301 https://domain.b/api/route/$1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can isolate the `/` URI by using the `location = /` syntax. This may work for you:

```
location = / {
    return 301 https://domain.b/;
}
location / {
    return 301 https://domain.b/api/route$uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thanks alot! Works!